# Specifying X resources for XTerm

Tags: xterm, x-resources

Where and how have to be put resources for an X-application (xterm, for instance) in the quoted os ?

I tried almost all the tricks I knew:

1) 
search for a system-wide `XTerm` file in a directory `app-defaults` and adding there my own resources: I found one in `/usr/share/doc/neXtaw/app-defaults`, but neither copying it in `/usr/share/X11/app-defaults` nor in `/usr/lib64/X11/app-defaults` made the resources to be recognized.

2)
Create both a `.Xresources` and a `.Xdefaults` file in my `home directory` with the required resources, written in all possible syntaxes (making use of dots and asterisks as you wish): for instance

```
     *XTerm*VT100*height: 1000
```

There was no way to have this resource applied...

3)
Naming in turn `.Xresources` and `.Xdefaults` as `XTerm`: no success...

So what can be done?

Comment: I forgot: I have also used editres to set the resource in the running application, again without any success.

Answer (score 3):

After modifying `.Xresources` as follow:

```
XTerm.VT100.geometry: 80x1000
```

You have to merge the resources:

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

I could not find any reference to `VT100*height`.

Comment: The  `height` resource was only a (wrong) sample. The problem held true for valid resources too. Anyway I found another solution, as I quote in the answer to my own question.

Answer (score 1):

Naming `.Xdefaults-myhostname` in the `home` directory the file with the customized resources (instead of simply `.Xdefaults`) works without merging anything. Of course `myhostname` stands for the output of the `hostname` command...